# show hide html code/content using nav menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a single pay-per-click (PPC) landing page that has a menu at the top of Home / Services / About

I do not want to have two other pages for Services/About. I just want to change the content & replace everything including and after `div class="inner"` through `!--inner--` based on a services click or about click.

So when landing on the page the home content defaults but when the services nav is clicked, it just changes everything including and after `<div class="inner">` through `<!--inner-->` html content and all.

Comment: It is the landing page for a Pay Per Click campaign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put contents in DIV and show/hide depending on the menu button clicked. Refer example below

```
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>PPC</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function ShowContent(content) {
             document.getElementById("divHome").style.display = 'none'
             document.getElementById("divAbout").style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById("divServices").style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById(content).style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>

        <a id="lnkHome" href="#" onclick="return ShowContent('divHome');" >Home</a>
        <a id="lnkAbout" href="#" onclick="return ShowContent('divAbout');" >About</a>
        <a id="lnkServices" href="#" onclick="return ShowContent('divServices');" >Services</a>

        <div id="divHome" style="display:block">Home Contents</div>
        <div id="divAbout" style="display:none">About Contents</div>
        <div id="divServices" style="display:none">Services Contents</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You! Most of the code I tried would not pass the HTML code without breaking the script, this works with HTML!

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery and some effects:

```js
$(function() {
  $('nav a').click(function() {
    // Get the section to show
    var $section = $('#' + $(this).data('section'));

    // If its already visible, do nothing.
    // Otherwise, hide the others and then fade in the desired section.
    if (!$section.is(':visible')) {
      $('.hideable-section').hide();
      $section.fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #7ca6e0;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.hideable-section {
  display: none;
}
.hideable-section:first-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a data-section="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-section="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a data-section="services">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="home" class="hideable-section">Home Content</div>
<div id="about" class="hideable-section">About Content</div>
<div id="services" class="hideable-section">Services Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to load all the content of your "single page application" at the start.  Each of the sections would be wrapped in their own `<divs>`.  Only the div for the "Home" data would be shown while other `<div>`'s would be hidden.  When the menu selection changes, other divs would be shown and others hidden.

Comment: yes but I have no idea how to make it work. I have tried show/hide functions with no luck

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //HIDE ALL CONTENTS
  $(".content").hide();
  //EVENT CLICK
  $(".menu a").click(function(event){
   //PREVENT RELOAD
    event.preventDefault();
    
    //HIDE ALL CONTENTS
    $(".content").hide();

    //GET ID FROM NEW CONTENT TO SHOW
    var id_content = $(this).attr("href");
    //SHOW NEW CONTENT
    $(id_content).show();
    
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#about" class="active">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- CONTENT--->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="about" class="content">
    content from about
  </div>
  <div id="services" class="content">
other content info from services
  </div>
</div>
<!---END CONTENT-->
```