# How to manage undefined when php is echoing javascript to call function to update navigation menu that doesn't return anything?

Tags: javascript, php, html, undefined

I am using a navigation menu functionality as described in the solution of this post:
[show hide html code/content using nav menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745253/show-hide-html-code-content-using-nav-menu)

It updates what is displayed on the page when a menu item is clicked. I added an 'active' class to highlight the menu that is currently selected.

Since the page is all one page, after running some php, I'm returned to the same page, but the page reloads and the menu goes back to Home. I'd like to keep the user on the same menu selection.

Further down the page, I am using php to try run through the navigation menu function again to get the menu to update.  This works, however, I get 'undefined' written to the browser at the bottom of the page.

I understand this happens because the javascript function doesn't return anything, it just updates elements. Thus, it returns undefined.

I've tried try/catch. I've tried setting the executed command to a variable and writing to console.log. Nothing works. It always says undefined. It will write to console, too, but it's always on the browser screen.

php echoing script to call function...

```
<?php
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['navMenu']) && $_SESSION['navMenu'] == 'divEvents') {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  
        document.write(ShowContent('divEvents'));
        </script>";
    }
 ?>
```

Navigation Menu code

```
function ShowContent(content) {
document.getElementById("divHome").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("divEvents").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("divNews").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("divAbout").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById(content).style.display = 'block';

if (content == "divHome"){
    document.getElementById("lnkHome").classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkEvents").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkNews").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkAbout").classList.remove('active');
    
}
if (content == "divEvents"){
    document.getElementById("lnkEvents").classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkHome").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkNews").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkAbout").classList.remove('active');
    
}
if (content == "divNews"){
    document.getElementById("lnkNews").classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkHome").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkEvents").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkAbout").classList.remove('active');
    
}
if (content == "divAbout"){
    document.getElementById("lnkAbout").classList.add('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkHome").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkEvents").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("lnkNews").classList.remove('active');
    
}
```

}

Is it possible to suppress 'undefined' from the page? Is it possible to execute an onclick some other way that doesn't result in 'undefined'?

Thank you.

Comment: Just don't use `document.write`?

Comment: I don't know where the `undefined` is coming from - there's not enough code here to see, but it does sound like you should be using AJAX for this content update, and you're not.

Comment: EL_Vanja - if I remove document.write, the function won't execute.

Tangentially - The function I am calling doesn't return anything, it just updates some HTML. When ever a function is called that doesn't return anything (in javascript) it results in undefined. It's a "feature" of javascript. "Implicitly, without return statement, a JavaScript function returns undefined." The undefined is coming from that. I think you are right that AJAX might be the way to go, I can just keep them on the same menu page.

Comment: _if I remove document.write, the function won't execute_ ...that isn't true. have you tried? `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ShowContent('divEvents');</script>";`

Comment: ADyson, yes I tried, and it didn't appear to execute. That is, the navigation menu didn't update. If something happened in the middle to prevent it, I don't know what that would have been. When I use document.write the navigation menu updates. That is why I am surmising that it didn't work.

Comment: `If something happened in the middle to prevent it, I don't know what that would have been`...were there any errors in the console? Did you use the browser's debugger to step through the code line by line and see what's happening. If you've got something like that which seems odd you need to debug it. Can we see the rest of the function?

Comment: ADyson - You are right. There must have been something goofy in my if statement. Removing that and removing document.write would update the navigation menu. It was my misunderstand from another post that document.write was needed.  But that was only get a returned value. Since nothing is being returned, I was getting undefined. Removed document.write and undefined is not returned an printed to screen. Thanks for having me closer look.  (updated the nav menu code as you requested anyway.

Comment: El_Vanja - Having a second look at this, you are correct. removing document.write was the solution. Thank you.