# Html: Left Side Menu Show hide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Just like the image I want to make, when `Home` is clicked, it is located in the `navigation-aside-wrapper` on the right.
Opening the `navigation-aside-item` page, I couldn't figure out how to do this. I would love it if you could help.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3yMR.png)

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="navigation-wrapper">
      <div class="navigation-aside-item">
        <span>Home</span>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation-aside-item">
        <span>About</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation-aside-wrapper">
    <div class="navigation-aside-item">
      Home Child
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-aside-item">
      About Child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: What I want to do is click "Home", I want its window to open.

Comment: Do you want to achieve something like vertical pills as mentioned here?https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navs/
Or 
The side bar like this?
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_sidebar.asp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to show different page content when you click an menu item you can use Javascript to show the correct content for each button.

Here is a post that shows how to do this. [show hide html code/content using nav menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745253/show-hide-html-code-content-using-nav-menu)